# Using Web Services with android

Tags: android, web-services

I want to know every bit knowledge of the two web services like Restful and SOAP integrating with android application..
Please help me! from where should I start?

Comment: Have you tried to search in google first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **REST API** u shld check the video for Google Rest and For **KSOAP** u should check in Google there are so many examples out there

Comment: Thanks.....you are a Good Error Handler...!! This Name suites you...

Answer (score 0):

SOAP is not really supported in Android, but it can be done with KSOAP.  For a good primer on REST check out Google's IO talk on the subject [GOOGLE IO RESTful Android](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html)

Comment: Hey Thanks Addicted Dear.........Its helpful...